# Problems setting up SQLDelight

Tags: android, sqldelight

I'm trying to use SQLDelight in my project. Everything seems to be working alright in respect of code generation. Unfortunately I can't use the interfaces generated under `/build/generated/source/sqldelight/...` in my project. When I try to create a class implementing a generated model it gets underlined with the error `cannot resolve symbol 'InterfaceName'`.
I prepared an example project showcasing my problem [here](https://github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/TestSQLDelight). Any help getting it to work is of course much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the sqldelight plugin on the app, not the project. In your application `build.gradle` file, right below `apply plugin 'com.android.application:'` put `apply plugin: 'com.squareup.sqldelight'`